# how to add extra space between items in dynamic spinner

Tags: android

Hey i am creating a spinner dynamically..it creating fine..no problem with that...but items are separate with narrow gap thats why one item is almost attached with others...i want a gap between items.please help
my code is like below..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(BidActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,result1);
        spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image: here is my screen shot that shows how congested this items are]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Custom Spinner Layout for this type of achievement. 
Go to this Link [custom-layout-for-spinner-item](http://fatoumatabintou.blogspot.in/2012/02/custom-spinner-with-icon-and-text.html) used this and customized by your own way.
thnks

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is please go for a custom spinner for which you can see the code at

http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286

http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107

http://www.edureka.in/blog/custom-spinner-in-android/